# How to filter data of last record of each week

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a big data set of daily selling value of a particular ITEM. I want to know what was the price of ITEM on the last day of each week. Typically the last working day is Friday but if you don't have data for Friday then we need to get the previous working day data (Thursday).

Monday is considered the First day of week.

My Data looks something like this:
[image: DATA SET]

Data is in cells A2:C13.

My expected output is shown below:
[image: Expected Output]

Please help with VB macro or even simple excel formula.

Comment: The Logic that I have tried is to get WEEKNUM, WEEKDAY and YEAR from date and then for each YEAR-WEEKNUM combination trying to find the largest WEEKDAY. Onc I am a beginner so not able to convert my logic into code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please note that because this is no free code writing service it is necessary to show either what you have tried so far and where you got stuck or errors (by showing your code) or at least to show what you have researched and the effort you made. Otherwise it is just asking us to do all the work for you. Reading [ask] might help you to improve your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try using a formula using the LOOKUP function, to [search the list from bottom to top.](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3404-excel-vlookup-from-bottom.html)

Afterward, a combination of INDEX and MATCH may get you on the right path as well.

Edit: I realize now that I was leading you astray because I thought you were asking something else! The most straightforward way I can see is as follows:

- use WEEKDAY() to pull out the weekday values (as you did), except leave the values as numbers (with 1 being Sunday and 7 being Saturday).
- Check each of these days to see if it precedes (i.e. has a lesser value) than the day above it. If not, we know that the week started over, and that cell is the last day of the week. Therefore, display its value.

[image: Example code]

Of course, this assumes that there are no Saturdays in your data - otherwise, Saturday would be listed as the end of the week. If you're crafty you can fix this dilemma though!

Comment: Edit: I realize now that I was leading you astray because I thought you were asking something else! The most straightforward way I can see is as follows:

- pull out the values on the last days of the weeks is to start with the WEEKDAY function as you did, except leave the values as numbers (with 1 being Sunday and 7 being Saturday).
- check each of these days to see if precede (i.e. have a lesser value) than the day above each. If not, we know that the week started over, and that cell is the last day of the week. Therefore, display its value

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Tyler.

Your suggestion helped me a lot in putting efforts in the right direction.

The way I did is as follows:

1. First I sorted my data in decreasing order of date so that I can have all the latest data at the top.

```
Range("AW4:BE999999").Sort Key1:=Range("BC4:BC999999"), order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
```

2. From Date created a string of "YEAR"&"WEEKNUM". This way I was able to group all the days in a specific week. Formula Used is:

```
    =(TEXT(BC5,"yyyy"))&(TEXT(WEEKNUM(BC5),"00"))
```

3. Then I gave a unique Number to each record. The best way I could think of is to give the row number where record belongs.

```
    =ROW(AY5)
```

4. Now using VLOOKUP function I got all the records matching string I have created in step 2

```
=VLOOKUP(AZ5,AZ:BD,5,FALSE)
```

I applied the above formula to get all the columns that I need.

5. Now I removed all the duplicate rows using below formula:

```
Cells.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)
```

Now the remaining rows are the expected rows.

There may be a better way to do this but this is my first time with excel macro and formulas, so feeling happy.

Please comment other better ways to do this. It's always good to keep on improving our work.